# Prve that $x^4+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I try Eisenstein's Criterion, replacing $x$ as $x+1$, $x+2$ or $x-1$. But they are the forms we need.

Comment: it has no roots since it is always strictly positive on $\mathbb R$. This means it has two couples of complex roots, so you have to check it doesn't split into the product of two quadratic polynomial with rational coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^4+x^2+x+1$. Suppose that $f$ is not irreducible. $f$ has no rational root by the rational root theorem. Hence $f$ does not factor as $(x-\alpha)(x^3+\ldots)$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$.

Thus $f$ is the product of two polynomials of degree $2$. Since the leading coefficient of $f$ is $1$, and the constant coefficient is $1$ as well, either $\forall x, f(x)=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1)$ or $\forall x, f(x)=(x^2+ax-1)(x^2+bx-1)$.

In the first case, equating coefficients of degree $3$ and $1$ yields $0=a+b=1$. In the second case, the same reasoning yields $0=a+b=-1$.